# What's the best way to train marines?

Tags: x3-albion-prelude

When training marines, there are 4 options: Hacking, Mechanical, Engineering and All Skills. Does training all skills simply distribute the experience a marine would receive by focusing on one skill to all three, or is it actually faster? Similarly, do the 3 different levels of training (Quick, Normal, Advanced) have the same teaching rate, or are more expensive options faster?

What's the fastest way for a marine to achieve maximum skill in:

1. Engineering and Hacking or Mechanical;
2. All three skills.

Comment: It isn't directly relevant to your question, but fighting skill can be upgraded by boarding empty ships in Retrieve Ship missions - there aren't any shields or hostile fire to worry about, but the marines still have to fight their way to the bridge and therefore earn fighting skill for doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Advanced training all skills is most cost-effective. But training time increase radicaly with current skill of marine.

According to [this discussion](http://steamcommunity.com/app/201310/discussions/0/828937262018734455/), you don`t need all marines trained in all skills. During boarding checked skills of 1 or 2 marines.

Use of Boarding pod increase Engineering skill.

Comment: Credit cost is actually the least of my concerns, I'm more interested in training them up as fast as possible.

Comment: Training one skill is faster then training all of them. Advanced training is most time-effective too.